# C#: How do i position a menuitem

Tags: c#, menu, move

How do i set the position of a menuitem all the way to the right, as shown in the picture, and make sure it stays there when resizing the dockbar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the menu item's `Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Right`